# R best fit of 45 degree line

Tags: r, model-fitting

(i know it must be incredibely easy, but i'm strugling with it in R:)

i have dataset of x and y values saved in X and Y vectors. I know that plot of the data should follow exactly -45 degree line (see image below)

[image]

How do i find such -45 degree line that best fits the data (+ all these statistics available from summary(lm(...))? I've tried lm, but i can't force it to abandon fitting the slope parameter

Thank you

After trying: `lm(y~1,offset=-x)` and applying `abline(coefficient, -1)` i obtain following plot (see below)
[image]

black line is abline plot, yellow one is mine guess of fit -- what's wrong with `lm` or do i miss totally something?

Comment: maybe `lm(y~1,offset=-x)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the solution from @BenBolker is correct and perhaps you are using the wrong coefficient:

```
lm1 <- lm(y~1,offset=-x,data=df)
plot(df)
abline(coefficients(lm1),-1)
```

This produces:

[image]

This fit looks like the correct fit to me.  The intercept is -2.217.

Comment: Yes, -2.217 should be intercept of best fit (manually tested), but when i put the same code (even with binding my data into data-frame to stick with your code strictly), i get intercept -1.42323 yelding the black line as shown above -- something is totally wrong

Comment: Hurray! Solved! the trouble was with the dataset which contained duplicated lines. After applying unique function to the dataset, lm returns the right interception! THANKS Everyone! :-)

Comment: (Thus the result was right from the beginning as far as the least y points have the biggest weights...)

Answer (score 2):

Since you state that:

y = -1*x + b

then

y+x = b

So calculate the mean of (y+x) and you get the average value of b

```
mean(y+x)
```

Comment: Thank you, but in additional i need those all statistics available from summary(lm(...)), i've forgot to write it into the question... I know i can calculate these separately, but i can bet that lm() function will be properly optimized for huge data which i plan to process...